# Using an Excel userform to launch queries with specific data as parameters

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

How can I send some userform datas to a query without printing them in a sheet ?

My current userform ask some [ Date / Name / File path ] using listBox and TextBox.
Depending of the choice of the user, some queries can be launch or not.
Obviously these queries are using the datas set in the userform.

I don't want to use the userform to print data in Excel and then start some queries that get their parameters from these last datas.

Is that possible ?

Comment: Welcome! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Potentially this sounds like you want to use out from a form, to populate one or more range names, then use those in powerquery.  Is that what you are trying to do? You can read the contents of a named range in powerquery using MVar = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]

Comment: @horseyride Yes that's already what I do and actually what I want to avoid. Is there any other solution to use a query with userform datas ?

Comment: Build the query from scratch, dynamically, using VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a sub that takes your parameters and rewrites a query for you. Here's an example of what I mean.

```vb
Sub ModifyPowerQuery(filePath As String)
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  
  Dim qry As QueryTable
  Set qry = wb.Queries("My Query") ' Modify the existing "My Query" power query
  
  ' Set the new command text for the query
  qry.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM """ & filePath & """"
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  
  Dim qt As QueryTable
  Set qt = ws.QueryTables("My Query") ' Modify the existing query table on the worksheet
  
  qt.Refresh ' Refresh the query to load the data from the new file
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you telling me that I can edit a variables inside my query ?

Comment: So I just saw that I can totaly rewrite my query from scratch with vba, that's in some way a solution to me. Thanks SSlinky to show me this tips !!